# Copy several folders and files from a git repository to another while preserving history

Tags: git, github, bitbucket-server

I have a repo on github/bitbucket called X, here's the directory structure

`├── folder1
    ├── folder2
    ├── folder3
    ├── folder4
    │   ├── a.cpp
    │   └── b.cpp
    ├── c.cpp
    └── d.cpp`

I want to make a new repo called Y, which should have

`├── folder1
    ├── folder4
    │   └── a.cpp
    └── c.cpp`

The commit history of all the files should be preserved, and also the directory structure of X to be intact, how can I do this?

Also if the above is possible, I don't want to move these files out of X because they are required by other files in X but want to work on them in repo Y and then push those changes to X somehow. I don't want change the directory structure of X or make the copied folders as submodules either. How can I make changes in the copied files and folders in Y and push those changes to a desired branch in X?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm... What you are suggesting is to have two separate repos working on some of the same files, but in the same directory. As far as I am aware you can't have that exact setup. But I also think it's not a very good setup - you are breaking "encapsulation" rules.

What would be better is to have:

repo `X`:

`├── folder1
    ├── folder2
    ├── folder3
    ├── folder4
    │   └── b.cpp
    ├── common (submodule called "common")
    |   ├── c.cpp
    │   └── a.cpp
    └── d.cpp`

Repo `Y`:

`├── folder1
    ├── common (submodule called "common")
    |   ├── c.cpp
    │   └── a.cpp
    └── e.cpp (repo Y only files)`

repo `common`

`├── c.cpp
      └── a.cpp`

So here you have three git repos: X, Y and Common.
Common is a submodule in X and Y. This is a better way to structure you project.

Then your common submodule keeps a shared history (well, its own history) and your specific X and specific Y files have their own separate history.

To get to there from where you are you need to create the two new repos (`Y` and `common`):

- Move in the common files into common.
- Move the Y files into Y.
- Include the common submodule into X and Y: `git submodule add <url to common>`
- Commit and push the changes to each repo.

Well, that's the rough outline of it. If you want further clarification just ask...

**Note:** If you want the directory structure exactly intact you could name "common" to "folder4" but it would still need to be a submodule.. but I think a slight re-work of your folders is better to move all the common stuff into one place.

**update 1**

From @J.Doe's request here is how you can create Y from X, but without submodules you this will have copies of files from Y...

- `mkdir Y` - create new folder (outside of any git repo)
- `cd Y` - move into that folder
- `git init` - turn this into a git repository
- `cp -r <path-to-X\folder1> .` - copy folder1 into repo
- `mkdir folder4` - create a folder 4.
- `cp <path-to-X\folder4\a.cpp> folder4` - copy a.cpp
- `cp <path-to-X\c.cpp> .` - copy c.cpp
- `git add -A` - add all files into the repo (stage them)
- `git commit -m "initial version of Y"` - commit the files to the repo
- `git remote add origin <url to remote Y>` - add the remote Y repo (you will have to create this in github first).
- `git push origin master` - assuming you are on the master branch (the default) push your initial commit to the remote.

As I said this will create repo Y with copies from X as a separate repo with a new history. If you want to have the history from X you can do that as well, but the method is slightly different.

**update 2**

To create Y with the history of X preserved:

- `cp -r X Y` - make a copy of X but call it Y
- `cd Y` - cd into Y (note this is still just a copy of X)
- `rm -r folder2 folder3 folder4/b.cpp d.cpp` - remove the files you don't want in Y
- `git add -A` - add all changes (in this case git will detect the delete files)
- `git commit -m "Y Created from X - initial version"`
- `git remote rm origin` - remove the remote pointing to X on github.
- `git remote add origin <url to Y on github>` - add remote to Y on github
- `git push origin master` - push the new repo to Y.

Note: here you will have the entire history of X in repo Y. Y will now move on separately from X (i.e. diverge).

**NOTE:** one problem with your requirement is that git does not work on individual files.

Comment: In the directory structure mentioned for Y, how exactly can I copy the folder 1 into Y from X (git commands wise), and also I won't be making changes in the copied files in X, but they have to be present at the same paths nonetheless, I can look for a way to push changes and commits/revisions to X done in Y somehow, but please help with how I can have this directory structure in Y without submodules, 
    ├── folder1
    ├── folder4--a.cpp
    └── c.cpp

Can you tell the git commands and their order for copying folders in this way and making a new repo Y from X?

Comment: @J.Doe I have added an update to show you the likely steps you will need to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate, that does work but it doesn't preserve the commit history though, surely there must be some way of doing that, is this such an uncommon requirement, moving a file and folder into another repo with their history?

Comment: @J.Doe we can do that as well - as I said the method is slightly different. I can add that as well... one sec

Comment: This answer works, thanks. I don't get your meaning in the 'NOTE', I can't get c.cpp file in Y since it's an individual file? Or I can't get it's history if I do git add c.cpp?

Comment: @J.Doe What I mean is that each commit is a blob of files. There is no specific history for any one file, they all share the same repository history. This is a difference between git and say...clearcase, or even SVN (i.e. in SVN you can commit individual files). In git you commit a change set weather its one file or many files that have change - all files are now part of the new commit hash ID.